# Windows 2K8 R2 in AD environment not allowing SMB connections

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, server-message-block, windows-firewall

I've got 2 Windows2k8R2 VMs. One is the domain controller, the other one is a TS server. Both have network discovery and file sharing enabled.

Currently the TS server is not allowing any SMB connection, either from domain local machines, workgroup local machines or even from the domain controller server. All local machines and the Active Directory server can communicate each other with SMB, RDP and ping echo. The TS server allows RDP and ping echo from any computer. It is just SMB connection protocol that is being rejected.

I have checked firewall rules and all "file and sharing" are allowed for incoming and outgoing connections. Also the Network Access policies are setup properly. most of them have default settings, and the ones that are not, are just for for the site requirements, nothing network related. Also, I tested turning the firewall off, antivirus off (Symantec Endpoint Protection) but no difference.

Does anybody has a clue about what could be the problem?

Comment: Also, permissions are set to everybody on the share and on the actual folder.

Comment: Have you tried access it with IP, Hostname + FQDN? Does it work "locally" from the TS? (i.e. \\localhost\blah)

Comment: Hi MichelZ. Thanks for the reply. Yes it does work locally, no problem mapping local shares. I tried from AD server or any other machine in the LAN using hostname + FQDN but nothing. I thought it was probably a DNS misconfiguration, but it doesn't work using IP either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been found and corrected.

The Symantec Endpoint Protection unmanaged client was installed on the TS server but not linked with the SEP Manager located on the AD server. Therefore, even after disabling the symantec protection, the firewall was still blocking traffic through port 445.

Once the communication XML link file was created and imported to the SEP on the TS server, the  SMB communication started working again properly.